# How to get the response in Playwright c# on click of button?

Tags: c#, automation, playwright

I have the following code :

```bash
private async Task ClickSaveTrade() => await _page.Locator("//btn[@ng-if ='model.isSavable() &&    !model.isSavePromptable()']").ClickAsync();

       await ClickSaveTrade();
       var res = await _page.WaitForRequestAsync(request =>
                 request.Url.Contains("TradeListing/SaveTrade"));
```

on click of ClickSaveTrade button SaveTrade Api request is called i need to read the response to get unique id of the trade, however in this code on _page.WaitForRequestAsync error occurred -

```
System.TimeoutException: 'Timeout 30000ms exceeded while waiting for event "Request
Inner Exception - TimeoutException: Timeout 30000ms exceeded while waiting for event "Request"
```

```bash
var actualResp = await _page.WaitForRequestAsync(urlOrPredicate: "https://..../SaveTrade");

var getResp = await actualResp.ResponseAsync(); // Use .Response to get the response

  // Assuming you want to access properties of the response
  var responseUrl = getResp.Url;
```

I tried this code as well but its not working